Trying to use Swagger version 2.0 (not talking about OpenAPI)
I inherited a project from a coworker and its a simple REST API built with ASP.NET Core off of Visual Studio 2022. The version of Swagger it is using is 1.0 with OpenAPI v3.0.1. I would like the Swagger version to at least be updated to 2.0 so I can Import it successfully into Postman. Any help on how to update my API to v2.0 (as well as terminology, only my second day looking at this).

share the top of the file as a code block.. does it say openapi: 3.0.0 or swagger: 2.0 ?

{
"openapi": "3.0.1",
"info": {
"title": "Five9API",
"version": "1.0"
}

what are you referring to when you say "it's using Swagger 1.0"?   Swagger is the original name of OpenAPI before it changed. There exists a version of Swagger: 2.0 which pre-dates OpenAPI 3.0.x.  Are you using Swashbuckle or some other library that generates code from an OpenAPI description?

@JeremyFiel I attached an image below
